# How to get class instance using assigned "id" variable?

Tags: python, oop

Is it possible to get the `wooden_sword` object using the `id` variable in the `Item` class?

```
class Item:
    __ids = count(0)

    def __init__(self):
        self.id = next(self.__ids)


class Weapon(Item):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


wooden_sword = Weapon()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have the `__init__` of `Item` store to a shared (class attribute) `WeakValueDictionary` and you can do lookup that way from an alternate constructor (`classmethod`):

```
import weakref

class Item:
    id_to_item = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()
    __ids = count(0)

    def __init__(self):
        self.id = next(self.__ids)
        self.id_to_item[self.id] = self

    @classmethod
    def from_id(cls, id):
        return cls.id_to_item[id]
```

`Item.from_id` can raise an exception (probably `KeyError` like a normal `dict`; test it) if the object corresponding to that `id` has been garbage collected; using a plain `dict` would avoid that issue, though it risks memory "leaks" (not a real leak; the object is available, but might never be used again).